# live search with jquery and json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a live search and then select those suggestions for further implementation!But it doesn't put values in the select field.In other words,option tag is not working!!!
here is the code!!!

//index.php

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Live Search</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="searcharea">

    <label for="search">live search</label>
    <p>Enter the name</p>
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="name or info">

</div>
<div>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="basic.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

//location.json

```
[
  {
    "name":"Barot Bellingham",
    },
  {
    "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
    },
  {
    "name":"Hillary Hewitt Goldwynn-Post",
    },
  {
    "name":"Hassum Harrod",
    },
  {
    "name":"Jennifer Jerome",
    },
  {
    "name":"LaVonne L. LaRue",
    },
  {
    "name":"Constance Olivia Smith",
    },
  {
    "name":"Riley Rudolph Rewington",
    },
  {
    "name":"Xhou Ta",
    }
]
```

//basic.js

```
$('#search').keyup(function()
{
    var searchField=$('#search').val();
    var myExp=new RegExp(searchField,"i");
    var slct_start='<select>';
    $('#top').html(slct_start);
    $.getJSON('location.json',function(data)
    {   
        var output='<ul class="searchresults">';    

        $.each(data,function(key,val){

            if(val.name.search(myExp)!=-1)
            {
             output='<option '+'value='+val.name+'>'+val.name+'</option>';

            }
        });
            $('#center').html(output);
    });//get json

    var slct_end='</select>';
    $('#bottom').html(slct_end);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this KeyUp function,
You can use the Jquery AutoComplete functionality for easy search.
Try that one.

Refer this [AutoComplete search in Jquery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: I love [select2](https://select2.github.io/) for this. Loading JSON on each keyStroke is bad programming anyway !

Comment: how can i convert jason data in an external location.json file into javascript???

Comment: declare the JSON data in the same page that holds the Jquery function, instead of other file

Comment: im updating location.json through server.how can i assign json object to javascript variable like: var obj=[{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"},{"name":"e"},{"name":"f"}].

Answer (score 1):

I found that your location.json's data is not standard, it should like this:

```
 [
  {
    "name":"Barot Bellingham"
    },
  {
    "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II"
    },
  {
    "name":"Hillary Hewitt Goldwynn-Post"
    },
  {
    "name":"Hassum Harrod"
    },
  {
    "name":"Jennifer Jerome"
    },
  {
    "name":"LaVonne L. LaRue"
    },
  {
    "name":"Constance Olivia Smith"
    },
  {
    "name":"Riley Rudolph Rewington"
    },
  {
    "name":"Xhou Ta"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

first we put a html file as index.html

```
   <div class="container">
  <h4 class="publish-work" >PUBLISHED WORKS AVAILABLE</h4>
  <br>
    <input type="search" class="search" name="search" >
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="datalist" class="table table-bordered" style="height: 400px;    overflow-y: auto;">
       <thead>

         <th>S.no</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Price</th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

then add a script.js file

$(document).ready(function()
{

```
var table_object = [];
for(var i=0; i<1500; i++)
{
    var object1 = [''];

    object1[0] = randomString() ;
    object1[1] = i+1;
    object1[2] = i*10/2;

    table_object.push( object1 );
}
console.log( table_object );


function render ( arraylist ) {

var html = '';
for(var i=0;i<arraylist.length;i++)
{


    //var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>'+arraylist[i][0]+'</td>';
    html += '<td>'+arraylist[i][1]+'</td>';
    html += '<td>'+arraylist[i][2]+'</td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    //html1 += html;
    //console.log(html);

}
    console.log(html);
    $("#datalist tbody").html(html);


}

render( table_object );

$(".search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var anotherval = [''];
    var dummyarray = [];
    for ( i=0; i<table_object.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( table_object[i]["name"].indexOf(value) != -1 )
        {
            dummyarray.push(table_object[i]);
        }
    }
    render(dummyarray);

});

function randomString ()
{

  var randomStringArray = [];
  var stringSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var maxLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
    var String = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
        String += stringSet[Math.floor(Math.random() * stringSet.length)];
    }

    randomStringArray.push(String);
   }
   return String;
}
```

});

thats it..